# List to Array Over LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've had a good look into this but im still very uncertain, could someone please let me know how I can optimize this into LINQ ? This seems a little old and im sure there is a  way to do this using LINQ.

```
Dim existingSpends(Spend.Count, 4) As Double
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
row = 0
For Each s As MarketingSpend_Chart In Spend
    existingSpends(row, 0) = s.field1
    existingSpends(row, 1) = s.field2
    existingSpends(row, 2) = s.field3
    existingSpends(row, 3) = s.field4
    row += 1
Next
```

Comment: What makes you think that LINQ would be any faster? It will essentially do a loop too, you know?

Comment: It look clear enought to me. LinQ way doesn't mean better, and sometimes is less maintenible.

Comment: ?Still would like to know if it can be done over LINQ

Comment: Perhaps the better optimization, especially for use with LINQ and with an eye toward modernization, would be to get rid of the 2 dimensional array and use a List of a class with the appropriate properties. But, if you want/need to keep the old style multi-dimensional arrays, then the solution is to use the old methods.

Comment: I think in `vb.net` you need `Dim existingSpends(Spend.Count-1, 3) As Double` as all arrays start from 0 and the max. index is specified, not the count.

Comment: What type of collection is `Spend`?

Answer (score 0):

Linq is designed to generate results that implement `IEnumerable`, such as `List`s and one-dimensional arrays.  I have not seen a linq method that can create a two-dimensional array.

If, however, you wanted to change your result set yo a *jagged* array you could do

```
MarketingSpend_Chart.Select(Function(s) New Double(4) {s.field1, _
                                                       s.field2, _
                                                       s.field3, _
                                                       s.field4}) _
                    .ToArray()
```

I agree with the comments, however, that Linq is unnecessary here.